# How I can get the number of files inside the folder in assets?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I know the number of images inside a particular file in assets What should I use?

Comment: A particular file, or a particular folder?

Comment: There is no difference I have a file in my project and inside it I want to know the number of images using the code

Comment: Number of images inside what? What type of file holds multiple images?

Comment: inside assets folder for example assets/Images/here all Images

Answer (score 1):

One line code

```
Int no_of_imgs = getResources().getAssets().list("foldar_name").length;
```

This works inside activity or fragment class.

Answer (score 1):

this code count android assets folder all files also containing in subfolders

```
private int countAssetFiles(String path) {
    int filesCount = 0;
    String [] list;
    try {
        list = getAssets().list(path);
        if (list.length > 0) {  
            for (String file : list) {
                // if there is a subfolder this line add count of that subfolder to  total count else add 1(one file)
                filesCount += listAssetFiles(path + "/" + file);
            }
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
         //path is a file
         return 1;
    }

    return filesCount; 
}
```

by below code you can get all files count in asset folder

```
int allFilesCount = countAssetFiles("");
```

if you want to get certain folder files in asset use this

```
int filesInSubFolder = countAssetFiles("/subFolderName");
```